# How to check whether user is logged in or not in asp .net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

Its first time I am creating a website using asp .net c# (using visual studio 2010). 
In this website, I have two types of user, having different accessible page. I have used two different tables to store thier username & password and used radio button in login form to select type of user.

There are four types of pages:
 1. Accessible to all (without / with login) or we can say public.
 2. Accessible only to type 1 user.
 3. Accessible only to type 2 user.
 4. Accessible to both type of users but not without login.

Now I really don't know how to implement this. Can any one please tell me the way/code to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the standard user and role providers, 1: anonymous 2: must be in role 1 3: must be in role 2 4: must be in role 1 or 2

Comment: use **session** with respective **flags** for different accessibility.

Comment: thanks for your comments but can you please tell me coding for this.

Comment: @SHAZ if I am getting you right, you are saying me to use session variables to pass flag bit between pages.

Comment: yes, u should set different session flags after validate. And go through this link: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

You should use membership role base approach in your database either using .NET pre-written library or your own schema to achieve what you are looking for.

then simply you could check everyone's role on page load to authorize each user for different page.

then in ASP.NET you could use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to check whether they logged in or not and `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole([role name])` to check different role names that's been allocated to different users.

Comment: thanks for your reply, now I am using role based authentication as explained on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET